# scaling factors in graphic (2D) programming

Tags: c#, autocad, cad, solidworks

What requirements must be taken in consideration when one tries to design/implement of a graphical environment to support scaling e.g. inch and centimeters?

how should then should be tackled?

Thanks.

Comment: Very unclear what you looking for. Are you looking for "how to display values using different measurement units"?

Comment: @Alexi, yes exactly that is the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Possible approach:

- pick a measurement units for internal representation
- define and use interface that let you convert internal units into UI strings (i.e. set of members like `FormatLength(double); FormatArea(double); FormatSpeed(double)`)
- provide necessary implementations of the interface (i.e. MetricFormats and UsFormats)
- provide a way to select implementation of the interface to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up it gave me some ideas but are there any URLs/Books/resources which can guide me on this path?

Comment: Not sure what help you are looking for... How to implement interface? How to show string in UI? How to pick one of several implementations of an interface via dropdown in UI? Or more generic - on conversions approaches - there are several questions on SO about units of measurement conversions, there is whole language feature in [F# - units of measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) to draw ideas from. If you made some progress and stuck - ask new question with code sample...